# Send message to group of user using SignalR

Tags: c#-4.0, signalr

I want to send a message only to users who are in my friend list. How can I do it using SignalR? Is there any special id I need to generate for each user while registration or primary key of user id is enough to send message? Meaning, in friends list if there are n number of user I want to send message only to them.

Comment: this question is really broad... try to be more specific about what you have tried and what is not working. Show us some of your code to help us understand what it is you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Create a group containing friends and send a message to this group.